# Self join query value mismatch

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Staffs and it is having column names are id, name, phone,manager_id

When I execute the self-join query it gives the wrong output. Please advise me

```
# id, name, phone, manager_id
'1', 'test1', '9089', NULL
'2', 'test2', '6877', '1'
'3', 'test3', '3656', '2'
'4', 'test4', '4324', '2'
'5', 'test5', '90', '3'
'6', 'test6', '5464', '4'
'7', 'test7', '5626', '3'
```

the values are in staffs table

what I tried

```
select e.name as employee,m.name as manager
 from staffs e
 inner join staffs m 
 on m.id=e.id 

 order by manager
```

it gives wrong output as

```
# employee, manager
'test1', 'test1'
'test2', 'test2'
'test3', 'test3'
'test4', 'test4'
'test5', 'test5'
'test6', 'test6'
'test7', 'test7'
```

Comment: You have a manager_id column. Why?

Comment: manager_id in a table represents the staffs may be an employee or a manager, I need a query to represent which are the employees are going to give status to which manager, @Strawberry

Comment: That was supposed to be a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT e.name as employee, m.name as manager
FROM staffs e LEFT JOIN staffs m ON e.manager_id = m.id 
ORDER BY m.name ASC
```

You join each staff with itself using `e.id = m.id`. But you want to show the manager of each staff so you have to use `e.manager_id = m.id`. By using a `LEFT JOIN` you can show all records with the name of the manager or without a manager name in case it is the manager itself.

Comment: Thank You for your valuable answer, It works as expected